# put the object files into a separate folder GNU make

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to generate the object files (.o files) into a separate folder. It worked well. The problem is the object files generated were not put into the folder I wanted them to be. The following is my makefile:

```
OBJDIR :=objdir
SOURCES=$(wildcard ./src/*.c)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))
vpath %.h ./src
vpath %.c ./src
optest : $(OBJS)
    cc -o optest $(OBJS)
$(OBJDIR)/main.o : add.h mul.h did.h
$(OBJDIR)/add.o : add.h
$(OBJDIR)/mul.o : mul.h
$(OBJDIR)/did.o : did.h

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)


clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    rm -f optest
```

My .h and .c files are put in the `./src` folder. The result of above makefile is that all the object files are also put in `./src` folder rather than the `objdir` folder. Can anyone give any suggestion?

Comment: You are overriding rules for `%.c`: files here: `$(OBJDIR)/main.o : add.h mul.h did.h`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues: you haven't substituted your source files correctly, and the implicit rule for compiling will only work for objects and sources with matching paths.

```
objdir  := objdir
sources := $(wildcard src/*.c)
objs    := $(sources:src/%.c=$(objdir)/%.o)
deps    := $(objs:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP

.PHONY: clean

optest: $(objs)
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(objs): $(objdir)/%.o: src/%.c | $(objdir)
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUPUT_OPTION) $<

$(objdir): ; mkdir $@

clean: ; $(RM) $(objs) $(deps) optest

-include $(deps)
```

Other stuff:

- Recycle the builtin recipes instead of rolling your own
- Use dependency generation instead of specifying each dependency manually
- Don't delete entire directories, even if you created them, stick to the files the makefile is responsible for
- Rules that don't actually make a file should be `.PHONY`.